# Unexpected behavior when concatenating pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have a relatively simple task: I have N pandas dataframes, each with 3 rows of data.  Most of the column names match up with all N dataframes (some of the dataframes might be missing 1 or two columns).  I want to create 3 new data frames containing N rows such that it is formed by concatenating the rows such that the i-th new dataframe will contain all the rows in row index i from all N dataframes.  Below is my attempt.

```
listOfRows1 = listOfRows2 = listOfRows3 = []
for i in range(N):
   dfN = pd.read_csv("filename"+str(i)+".csv")
   dfN["Index"] = range(1,4)
   listOfRows1.append(dfN[dfN["Index"]==1])
   listOfRows2.append(dfN[dfN["Index"]==2])
   listOfRows3.append(dfN[dfN["Index"]==3])
newdf1 = pd.concat(listOfRows1)
newdf2 = pd.concat(listOfRows2)
newdf3 = pd.concat(listOfRows3)
```

The result is an oddly formatted df that has some correct rows but does not match my desired output, even though when I print the listOfRows it seems that they look like they are pulling the correct rows from the N data frames.  It appears that for each new df, the result is just the entire N old data frames concatenated with each other, rather than just the respective rows desired.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to simply change the first line from

```
listOfRows1 = listOfRows2 = listOfRows3 = []
```

to

```
listOfRows1 = []
listOfRows2 = []
listOfRows3 = []
```

Thus, when appending to the vectors in the loop, the rows do not get appended to all of the vectors.